# Docker agent inside Jenkins - npm "cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on automation of following build steps:
- building frontend application with webpack
- running tests on it

I am using Jenkins with blue-ocean plugin enabled, here is **Jenkinsfile**:

```
Jenkinsfile:pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      filename 'Dockerfile'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm run build'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using following **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm install webpack -g && npm install
```

The problem is that when running `npm run build` it can not find webpack:

```
> webpack --config webpack-production.config.js --progress --colors

module.js:529
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/l-ui-webpack-example_master-IXSLD4CQSVAM2DRFHYHOYUANEHJ73R5PUGW4BMYVT5WPGB6ZZKEQ/webpack-production.config.js:1:79)
```

It looks like commands are being executed in host context, not on container as manual running works just fine:

```
docker build . -t sample
docker run sample npm run build
```

Here is full jenkins log:[Jenkins build log](https://gist.github.com/szromek/c2b369a2c855d85eb14aac6fc94ffcba)
Here is a link to a repository: [Source code](https://github.com/szromek/material-ui-webpack-example)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. For some reason, 'RUN npm install' within the Dockerfile didn't take effect in the Jenkins pipeline although it worked well when I built the image manually.

I got the pipeline working by running "npm install" as a step in the pipeline. So add this to your Jenkinsfile before the 'Build' stage:

```
stage ('install app') {
    steps {
        sh "npm install"
    }
}
```

I don't know why this happens but it might have something to do with how Jenkins sets the context for the Docker build. I hope someone else can elaborate on this.